# CountVectorizer Extracting features

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Dataframe

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|filtered                                        |
+------------------------------------------------+
|[human, interface, computer]                    |
|[survey, user, computer, system, response, time]|
|[eps, user, interface, system]                  |
|[system, human, system, eps]                    |
|[user, response, time]                          |
|[trees]                                         |
|[graph, trees]                                  |
|[graph, minors, trees]                          |
|[graph, minors, survey]                         |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

After running `CountVectorizer` on the above column i get the following output

```
+------------------------------------------------+-------------------

--------------------------+
|filtered                                        |features                                     |
+------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|[human, interface, computer]                    |(12,[4,7,9],[1.0,1.0,1.0])                   |
|[survey, user, computer, system, response, time]|(12,[0,2,6,7,8,11],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|
|[eps, user, interface, system]                  |(12,[0,2,4,10],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])            |
|[system, human, system, eps]                    |(12,[0,9,10],[2.0,1.0,1.0])                  |
|[user, response, time]                          |(12,[2,8,11],[1.0,1.0,1.0])                  |
|[trees]                                         |(12,[1],[1.0])                               |
|[graph, trees]                                  |(12,[1,3],[1.0,1.0])                         |
|[graph, minors, trees]                          |(12,[1,3,5],[1.0,1.0,1.0])                   |
|[graph, minors, survey]                         |(12,[3,5,6],[1.0,1.0,1.0])                   |
+------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Now i want to run a map function on features columns and convert it into something like this

```
+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|features                                        |transformed                                             |
+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|(12,[4,7,9],[1.0,1.0,1.0])                      |["1 4 1", "1 7 1", "1 9 1"]                             |
|(12,[0,2,6,7,8,11],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])   |["2 0 1", "2 2 1", "2 6 1", "2 7 1", "2 8 1", "2 11 1"] |
|(12,[0,2,4,10],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])               |["3 0 1", "3 2 1", "3 4 1", "3 10 1"]                   |
[TRUNCATED]
```

The way features transformed is by taking the middle array from features and then create sub-arrays from it. for example in row 1 and col 1 of `features` column we have

```
(12,[4,7,9],[1.0,1.0,1.0])
```

Now take its middle array which is `[4,7,9]` and compare its freq with the third column which is `[1.0,1.0,1.0]` prepend "1" as it's row 1 to get the following output:

```
["1 4 1", "1 7 1", "1 9 1"]
```

Which in general looks like this:

```
["RowNumber MiddleFeatEl CorrespondingFreq", ....]
```

I am not able to Extract the **Middle** and **Last** Freq **list** separately from features columns generated by `CountVectorizer` by applying map function:

So the following is the map code:

```
def corpus_create(feats):
    return feats[1] # Here i want to get [4,7,9] instead of 1 single feat score.

corpus_udf = udf(lambda feats: corpus_create(feats), StringType())
df3 = df.withColumn("corpus", corpus_udf("features"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row numbers are essentially meaningless in Spark SQL, but if you don't mind that:

```
def f(x):
    row, i = x
    jvs = (
        # SparseVector
        zip(row.features.indices, row.features.values) if hasattr(row.features, "indices")
        # DenseVector
        else enumerate(row.features.toArray()))

    s = ["{} {} {}".format(i, j, v) 
        for j, v in jvs if v]
    return row + (s, )


df.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(f).toDF(df.columns + ["transformed"])
```